# Are there any NP-complete problems that are also in IP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, interactive-proof-systems

I am wondering if anyone knows if there are any NP-complete problems that are also known to be in IP (interactive polynomial time).  I know problems like Graph Isomorphism are in IP, but such problems are not known to be NP-complete.

Moreover, if there were or were not an NP-complete problem in IP, what would be the consequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
IP = PSPACE
$$
According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_(complexity)).
Thus $NP \subseteq IP$ and all NP-complete problems are in $IP$.